# pass user object to controller action cause big delay

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, performance, json.net, telerik-mvc

When I am using Json.net or telerik grid and pass complex object to my controller action I have a strange delay for **600** milliseconds. Here is my code:

```
[Authorize, GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
public ActionResult AjaxItemsLoad(GridCommand command)
{
            var model = new GridModel();

            model.Data = null;
            model.Total = 0;

            return View("Index", model);
}
```

For test I change complex object with simple types (few strings or int32) and delay disappeared and response come for 70 milliseconds.

Then I disable default `JsonValueProviderFactory` but delay still same.

The question: what or who can cause such big delay for post request?

Thanks a lot

Comment: hm.. it's very interesting. did u find how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you may have 2 issues. First one is that I see you are using CustomBinding, have a look at the custom binding code that you are using, there could be an issue there. Secondly, do you have any sort of validation on your model, i.e. the object being passed to your controller action? – Nikron 28 mins ago